# Does GWT reuse Google Closure Compiler, and why if not?

Tags: javascript, gwt, minify, google-closure-compiler

[Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/) performs inlining of javascript code, minifying and removing unused code, and some other optimizations which are also done by [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/). So I was wondering if Closure Compiler is in fact utilized in GWT or do they have two separate implementations? If so, then what is the restriction/reasoning for not reusing Google Closure Compiler in GWT?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Commit 10778: Closure JS hookup](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/detail?r=10778) hooks GWT to the closure compiler.

Probably with GWT 2.5, at least behind the scenes, GWT may use the closure compiler.

---

### Update

[Closure Support has been removed](https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/#/c/15110/)

Comment: The 2.5RC announcement blog post (http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.dk/2012/06/gwt-2.html) mentions integration with the Google Closure Compiler.

Answer (score 3):

GWT does not currently use Closure Compiler, GWT does the bulk of its optimization while the code is in Java form.

While there are many aspects of CC that are redundant for GWT, there is some interest in using it, however it isn't as simple as simply post processing the GWT output as the default GWT "linker" makes the code opaque to CC.

Comment: CC will be an optional enhancement in GWT 2.5 as noted below.