# GWT and Closures

Tags: gwt, closures

I have used closures concept in javascript many times. I am new to GWT and I read somewhere it is not possible to use Closures in GWT. Is my understanding wrong or will I able to use it?
Can someone provide me an example of closure use in GWT.

Comment: +1 for your question.

This is not direct answer -

GWT code is written in Java ( closure support is on the horizon but not yet there ) and then compiled to Javascript.

GWT code can wrap Javascript in Java ( We call this JSNI and there you have closure )

GWT compiler has google closure compiler flag for optimizations http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368681/does-gwt-reuse-google-closure-compiler-and-why-if-not

Comment: So you are saying there is no support for this yet in GWT, but JSNI emulates it?. So can I have multiple native functions and have closure implemented in some other native method? Am I correct?

Comment: Yep. Waiting on our Stackoveflow GWT expert @ThomasBroyer to provide the exact answer :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equivalent of closures in Java are local classes, which can be anonymous (just like anonymous functions in JS).
Java 8 will bring us lambdas, but GWT isn't yet supporting Java 7, so lambdas in GWT are not for tomorrow ;-)

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)#Local_classes_.28Java.29